# Sitefinity 11: unable to access Content -> Blogs or other Dynamic Module sections

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I am using sitefinity 11 Trial version. I have come across a very strange issue.
I am trying to use **Content -> Blogs** section, when I click that option in menu, I am redirected to **"Sitefinity/adminapp/content/blogs"** page. Where it keeps loading, after a while it reloads the page not URL becomes **"Sitefinity/adminapp/"** then after some time URL becomes **"/Sitefinity/adminapp/auth/oidc/sign-in#id_token=XXXXXsomevalue"** then it keeps reloading there for always.

I have tried to "switch new interface" on/off but that didn't help either.
[image]

I also have created a Dynamic Module but same problem with that too.

I searched about this issue but no help. I also came across the [link](https://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/peter-filipov-blog/2018/05/30/how-to-extend-the-new-sitefinity-admin-app) but this was about customising the Admin backend screens.

Please guide me the right path.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an authentication cookie issue, did you change anything to do with security?

Comment: No. But i explained below how it worked.@JonR.can you please look into the following question for me:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50886620/sitefinity-11-cant-get-dropdown-selected-value-on-postback-in-frontend-widget-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange, I opened the sitfinity admin section in Internet Explorer. there I got the message that this browser is not supported, please switch to Classic mode. I again set the "switch new interface" to off in IE.

And I am able to access the Manage screens.

Then I cleared the browsing history on Chrome, re login into sitefinity admin section unselected the "Remember me" checkbox. And I can use the screens in chrome also.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is what type of authentication mode you are using.  (In Administration > Settings > Advanced > Security, the AuthenticationMode drop-down). Along with IE not being supported by the new Interface (which Edge, Chrome and Firefox are), the new interface also works best with Claims Authentication, which is Sitefinity's preferred authentication mode.  We found that when we switched from Forms Authentication to Claims that we had some similar functionality back even while in the new interface.  (Note that in Claims Authentication you'll use a different URL for logging in: https://sitename/Sitefinity instead of https:/sitename/Sitefinity/login with Forms Authentication).