# Sitefinity 11 Can't get dropdown selected value on postback in Frontend Widget Control

Tags: telerik, sitefinity, sitefinity-5, sitefinity-10, sitefinity-8

I am using Sitefinity 11. I have created a Custom Widget for News Module, having Drop down for all available Categories, where I need to filter the News for Selected Category. The Control postback's but it's SelectedIndex is always ZERO.

I have checked the checkbox for "Enable View State for this page" and Page is using custom Layout Template.

The code in my .aspx file is given below:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.News" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Taxonomies.Model" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Model" %>

    <%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.ContentUI" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Comments" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.PublicControls.BrowseAndEdit" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>


    <script type="C#" runat="server">

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                try
                {
                    var ControlID = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString();
                    Control postbackControl = Page.FindControl(ControlID);
                    lblStatus.Text = "ControlID=" + ControlID + "<br>";
                    DropDownList dd = (DropDownList)postbackControl;
                    lblStatus.Text += "SelectedIndex=" + dd.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    lblStatus.Text += "<br>" + ex.Message;
                }
            }
            var s = ddlCategories.SelectedIndex;
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                /* List of all categories */
                Telerik.Sitefinity.Taxonomies.TaxonomyManager manager1 = Telerik.Sitefinity.Taxonomies.TaxonomyManager.GetManager();
                System.Collections.IList categoryList = manager1.GetTaxa<Telerik.Sitefinity.Taxonomies.Model.HierarchicalTaxon>()
                                        .Where(t => t.Taxonomy.Title == "Categories")
                                        .Select(t =>
                                            new { Id = t.Id, Name = t.Title.ToString() })
                                        .OrderByDescending(t => t.Name)
                                        .ToList();
                ddlCategories.DataSource = categoryList;
                ddlCategories.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddlCategories.DataValueField = "Id";
                ddlCategories.DataBind();
                ddlCategories.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));

            }
        }
        protected void DdlCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.News.NewsManager newsManager = Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.News.NewsManager.GetManager();
            if (this.ddlCategories.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                //this.FilterExpression += string.Format(" AND Category.Contains(({0}))", this.ddlCategories.SelectedValue.ToString());
                Guid taxonFilter = new Guid(this.ddlCategories.SelectedValue.ToString());

                NewsList.DataSource = newsManager.GetNewsItems().Where(newsItem => newsItem.Status == Telerik.Sitefinity.GenericContent.Model.ContentLifecycleStatus.Live
                    && newsItem.GetValue<IList<Guid>>("Categories")
                        .Contains(taxonFilter)
                    ).ToList();
            }else {
                NewsList.DataSource = newsManager.GetNewsItems().Where(newsItem => newsItem.Status == Telerik.Sitefinity.GenericContent.Model.ContentLifecycleStatus.Live).ToList();}
            //populate items list
            //return base.GetItemsList(ref totalCount);
        }
    </script>

    <section class="news-container">
              <div class="container">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <!-- filter panel -->
                <div class="filter-panel">
                  <div class="panel-box categories">
                    <span class="label">CATEGORIES</span>
                    <div class="select-wrp">
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategories" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlCategories_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                      </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


    <sf:SitefinityLabel id="title" runat="server" WrapperTagName="div" HideIfNoText="true" HideIfNoTextMode="Server" /> 
    <telerik:RadListView ID="NewsList" ItemPlaceholderID="ItemsContainer" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false">
        <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="container extra-container2">
              <div class="row news-post">   
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemsContainer" runat="server" />
              </div>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>

            <article class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 post">
              <div class="holder">
                <h2><sf:FieldListView ID="Title" runat="server" Text="{0}" Properties="Title" TextMode="Encode" EditableFieldType="ShortText"/> </h2>

              </div>
            </article>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:RadListView>

    <sf:Pager id="pager" runat="server"></sf:Pager>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="socialOptionsContainer" runat="server" />

    </section>
```

**EDIT: Even following code is getting the same result.**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                /* List of all categories */
                Telerik.Sitefinity.Taxonomies.TaxonomyManager manager1 = Telerik.Sitefinity.Taxonomies.TaxonomyManager.GetManager();
                System.Collections.IList categoryList = manager1.GetTaxa<Telerik.Sitefinity.Taxonomies.Model.HierarchicalTaxon>()
                                        .Where(t => t.Taxonomy.Title == "Categories")
                                        .Select(t =>
                                            new { Id = t.Id, Name = t.Title.ToString() })
                                        .OrderByDescending(t => t.Name)
                                        .ToList();
                ddlCategories.DataSource = categoryList;
                ddlCategories.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddlCategories.DataValueField = "Id";
                ddlCategories.DataBind();
                ddlCategories.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));

            }
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                try
                {
                    var ControlID = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString();
                    Control postbackControl = Page.FindControl(ControlID);
                    lblStatus.Text = "ControlID=" + ControlID + "<br>";
                    DropDownList dd = (DropDownList)postbackControl;
                    lblStatus.Text += "SelectedIndex=" + dd.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    lblStatus.Text += "<br>" + ex.Message;
                }
            }
            var s = ddlCategories.SelectedIndex;
        }
```

please guide me what is missing?

Thanks

Comment: Probably because the categories are loaded only on !Postback, so on postback they are not there - try loading them before getting the selected index

Comment: I tried that too but Still the SelectedIndex is ZERO. See my edit.

Comment: Can the admins get some help regarding this?

Comment: Make sure the page has Enable Viewstate checked - this is in the Title and Properties

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the page has Enable Viewstate checked - this is in the Title and Properties of the page

Answer (score 0):

I have added a Hidden Field and I was able to get it's value after postback. Another solution was to send value in query-string.

Thanks for all replies.